# Css: Footer not going to bottom?

Tags: html, css, bulma

the footer will go to the bottom when the content is longer than the whole page, and you have to scroll down to see the footer, but when its just low content and no scroll, theres a space between the bottom and the footer?

I'm using bulma CSS framework, here is the code

```css
.footer {
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem 1rem;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 3rem 1.5rem 6rem;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i> &nbsp;&copy; 2017 - Project Name</p>
      <p class="copyright">Built on the EC9 Platform with <a href="https://laravel.com/" target="_new">Laravel</a>, <a href="https://bulma.io/" target="_new">Bulma</a> and <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></span>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Preview:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/KKntSao.png]

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/47

Comment: You'll need to look into sticky footers. A few different options to tackle can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Comment: You need to provide more information about how is your content structured, according to that, you can choose a number of options like @DollarChills mentioned

Answer (score 2):

your css code is duplicate for padding.

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
Hello
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i> &nbsp;&copy; 2017 - Project Name</p>
      <p class="copyright">Built on the EC9 Platform with <a href="https://laravel.com/" target="_new">Laravel</a>, <a href="https://bulma.io/" target="_new">Bulma</a> and <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></span>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **poistion: absolute; bottom: 0;** and add **margin-top** to it = its height (your footer).